# Django - Overriding get_or_create with models.py

Tags: django, django-models

I have a class in which I want to override the `get_or_create` method.  Basically if my class doesn't store the answer I want it do some process to get the answer and it's not provided.  The method is really a `get_or_retrieve` method.  So here's the class:

```
class P4User(models.Model):
  user      = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
  fullname  = models.CharField(max_length=256)
  email     = models.EmailField()
  access    = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
  update    = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

  @classmethod
  def get_or_retrieve(self, username, auto_now_add=False):
    try:
        return self.get(user=username), False
    except self.model.DoesNotExist:
        import P4
        import datetime
        from django.db import connection, transaction, IntegrityError
        p4 = P4.P4().connect()
        kwargs = p4.run(("user", "-o", username))[0]
        p4.disconnect()
        params = dict( [(k.lower(),v) for k, v in kwargs.items()])        
        obj = self.model(**params)
        sid = transaction.savepoint()
        obj.save(force_insert=True)
        transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
        return obj, True
    except IntegrityError, e:
        transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
        try:
            return self.get(**kwargs), False
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            raise e

  def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

Now I completely admit that I have used the db/models/query.py as my starting point.  My problem is this line.

`obj = self.model(**params)`

I am able to get the params but I haven't defined self.model.  I don't understand what that needs to be and it's not intuitively obvious what value that should be. Even looking back at the query.py I can't figure this out.  Can someone explain this to me?  I would really like to understand it and fix my code.

Thanks

Comment: Title misguiding the question you asked. There no where you're trying to override the get_or_create method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel was right in his suggestion to use a Manager class.  Here is what I ended up with.

```
# Managers

class P4Manager(models.Manager):
  def p4_run_command(self, command):
    """Runs a basic perforce command and return the values"""
    p4 = P4.P4()
    p4.connect()
    values = p4.run(command)
    p4.disconnect()
    return self.__unify_key_values__(values)

  def __unify_key_values__(self, args):
    """Unified method to clean up the lack of standard returns from p4 api"""
    final = []
    for item in args:
      params = dict( [(k.lower(),v) for k, v in item.items()])
      results = {}
      for k, v in params.items():
        if k in ['password', ]: continue
        if k in ["access", "update"]:
          v = datetime.datetime.strptime(v, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") 
        results[k]=v
      final.append(results)
    return final

  def __get_or_retrieve_singleton__(self, **kwargs):
    """This little sucker will retrieve a key if the server doesn't have it.
       In short this will go out to a perforce server and attempt to get a
       key if it doesn't exist.    
    """
    assert len(kwargs.keys())==2, \
            'get_or_retrieve() must be passed at one keyword argument'
    callback = kwargs.pop('callback', None)
    try:      
      return self.get(**kwargs), False
    except self.model.DoesNotExist:
      params = self.p4_run_command((kwargs.keys()[0], "-o", kwargs.values()))
      if callback:
        params = callback(*params)
      obj = self.model(**params)
      sid = transaction.savepoint()
      obj.save(force_insert=True)
      transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
      return obj, True
    except IntegrityError, e:
      transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
      try:
        return self.get(**kwargs), False
      except self.model.DoesNotExist:
        raise e

class P4UserManager(P4Manager):
  """
  A Generic User Manager which adds a retrieve functionality
  """
  def get_or_retrieve(self, user):
    kwargs = { 'callback' : self.__userProcess__ ,
               'user': user }
    return self.__get_or_retrieve_singleton__(**kwargs)

  def __userProcess__(self, *args):
    args = args[0]
    if not args.has_key('access'):
      raise self.model.DoesNotExist()
    return args

# Models

class P4User(models.Model):
  """This simply expands out 'p4 users' """
  user      = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
  fullname  = models.CharField(max_length=256)
  email     = models.EmailField()
  access    = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
  update    = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
  objects   = P4UserManager()

  def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

I hope other find this usefull

Answer (score 6):

`get_or_create` is a `Manager` method, that is you access it via model.objects - it is the manager class that has an attribute `model`. So maybe the easiest thing to do would be to create a custom Manager and put your method there.

However, fixing your code as it stands is easy. `self.model` is just the classname - that line is simply instantiating the class with the given parameters. So you could just do

```
obj = P4User(**params)
```

although this breaks if you subclass the model.

Comment: You are right on the money.  I ended up creating a manager.  I'll share that below for anyone else..

Answer (score 0):

Use **self** instead of **self.model**.

The code you are copying from, is method for class Queryset. There, **self.model** is the Model whose queryset is intended to be used. Your method is classmethod of a model itself.